# Devise omniauth scope to add user to business

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have devise set up, and I want users to be able to sign in / register like so:

http://awesomesite.com/businessName/users/sign_in

if they sign up on the businessName route, I want to make it so that they will automatically get added as users of the business entitiy.

I have omniauth and I know that omniauth cannot handle dynamic scoping and the routes for omniauth need to be explicitly set, because I got this error:

```
Devise does not support scoping omniauth callbacks under a dynamic segment (RuntimeError)
 You can work around by passing
 `skip: :omniauth_callbacks` and manually defining the routes. Here is an example:

match "/users/auth/:provider",
  constraints: { provider: /google|facebook/ },
  to: "devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru",
  as: :omniauth_authorize,
  via: [:get, :post]

match "/users/auth/:action/callback",
  constraints: { action: /google|facebook/ },
  to: "devise/omniauth_callbacks",
  as: :omniauth_callback,
  via: [:get, :post]
```

I did a bit of research and came up with this routes setup:

```
  scope '(:business)', locale: /acmecorp/ do
      devise_for :users, skip: [:invitation, :registration, :confirmation, :omniauth_callbacks], controllers: { :sessions => "devise/sessions", :registrations => "devise/registrations" }
      match "/users/auth/:provider",
        constraints: { provider: /google|facebook/ },
        to: "users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru",
        as: :omniauth_authorize,
        via: [:get, :post]

      match "/users/auth/:action/callback",
        constraints: { action: /google|facebook/ },
        to: "users/omniauth_callbacks",
        as: :omniauth_callback,
        via: [:get, :post]
  end
```

but I get this error:

`` undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc1214f1fe8>:0x007fc11cf711d0> ``

when I try to visit http://awesomesite/acmecorp/users/sign_in

I tried looking at the devise wiki and stackoverflow, but it just isn't clicking for me.

EDIT: running rake routes gives me this for the relevant routes:

```
                             Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                                       Controller#Action
                   new_user_session GET      (/:business)/users/sign_in(.:format)                                              devise/sessions#new
                       user_session POST     (/:business)/users/sign_in(.:format)                                              devise/sessions#create
               destroy_user_session DELETE   (/:business)/users/sign_out(.:format)                                             devise/sessions#destroy
                      user_password POST     (/:business)/users/password(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#create
                  new_user_password GET      (/:business)/users/password/new(.:format)                                         devise/passwords#new
                 edit_user_password GET      (/:business)/users/password/edit(.:format)                                        devise/passwords#edit
                                    PATCH    (/:business)/users/password(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#update
                                    PUT      (/:business)/users/password(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#update
                 omniauth_authorize GET|POST (/:business)/users/auth/:provider(.:format)                                       users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/google|facebook/}
                  omniauth_callback GET|POST (/:business)/users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)                                users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:google|facebook)
```

Comment: Look for the routes method path by running `rake routes`. Is `scope '(:business)'` a valid scope name?

Comment: @codyeatworld it would seem so, I've posted my rake routes output

Comment: Replace `user_omniauth_authorize_path` with `omniauth_authorize_path`.